# Medical term REST API

Tags: android, rest, cordova, ionic-framework

i am developing a Medical dictionary mobile application with ionic and i need a rest api to fetch medical terms to display on the application.

kindly help me any resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find lot of Api [Medical Api](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/medical/apis?category=19994)

Comment: i have tried finding couldnt get any..you could help me if u have one

Comment: https://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-medical-dictionary.htm

Comment: thanks for the resource